# Smart coding on ActionScript 2 (importing vars from a php)

Tags: php, flash, actionscript-2

i have a php who when is executed it give me a couple of vars in this format:

&**lVar1**=DATA1&&**lVar2**=DATA2&&**lVar3**=DATA3 and soo...

The problem is that i dont know the quantity of lVar the php script is gonna give in any time, so i cant figure out a smart script in AS2 to import all of them into a array to my flash. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't call this smart coding but, really, I can't think of any elegant way of doing this using *loadVars*:

```
loadText.onLoad = function() {
    var myArr:Array = new Array();
    for(i = 1; i <= loadText.total; i++) {
        myArr.push(eval("loadText.IVar" + i));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you gave me an exellent idea of how to resolve this with the eval function! +1